# Inserting into LinkedList and then Sorting by Ascending ID number

Tags: java, linked-list

I have random ID numbers assigned to my list items. I have a class containing the LinkedList, and a class representing the items in the list. This is what I have to do: The constructor in the LinkedList class should call a method to build a list of test data. These should be added to the LinkedList in sorted order.
After building the test data for the LinkedList, the constructor should call a method to print the items in the list to the command line.

I have most of the code, I just can't figure out how to sort the ID numbers in order, and also how to insert a new item to the list in the correct order. BELOW IS THE CODE I NEED TO EDIT TO MAKE THIS WORK:

```
    public boolean decideToInsert (Makeup ee) {
    boolean decision = false;
    //code goes here
    return decision;
```

Here is the LinkedList

```
package model;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MakeupList {

private LinkedList <Makeup> makeList = new LinkedList<>();
public MakeupList(){
    this.createMakeList();
    this.printMakeList();
}
public void createMakeList(){
    makeList.add(new Makeup("Natural Face", "Too Face"));

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        addMakeup (new Makeup ("Matte Lipstick", "MAC"));
}
}

public void addMakeup (Makeup newMake){
    boolean makeupAdded = false;
    boolean insertDecision = false;
    ListIterator<Makeup> makeIterator = makeList.listIterator();
    while (makeIterator.hasNext()){
        insertDecision = makeIterator.next().decideToInsert(newMake);
        if (insertDecision == true){
            makeList.add(makeIterator.previousIndex(), newMake);
            makeupAdded = true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(!makeupAdded){
        makeList.add(newMake);
    }
}
public void printMakeList(){
    ListIterator<Makeup> makeIterator = makeList.listIterator();
    while(makeIterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(makeIterator.next().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll assume , `Makeup` has a attribute `id` of type `int` and the list should end up sorted by `id` in ascending order. Could look like this then:  `decideToInsert (Makeup ee) { return ee.id >= this.id;}`. But watch out, if it never evaluates to `true` you must not add `newMake` at the end of the list but at the beginning.

Comment: You can reduce expressions like `if (a == true)...` to `if (a)...`. Personally I find the iterator-approach hard to comprehend, a for-loop might be clearer.

Comment: Then, are you sure using a `LinkedList` internally is actually your exercise, rather than building one [yourself](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-linked-list-in-java-using-class/)? Because right now you could just add all elements and sort the list in the end (`makeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.id))`)

Comment: Where you don't need an index to insert something, you can iterate using the enhanced for loop (["foreach"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/)) or the `forEach` method: `public void printMakeList(){
    makeList.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.toString());    
}`

Comment: Guriso this worked thank you so much!

Comment: yes? nice! Should have made an answer out of it maybe, ah, too late.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Comparable<T>` interface and `Collections#sort`

For example, implement the `Comparable<Makeup>` interface into your `Makeup` class, and in the method you receive

```java
public int compareTo(Makeup o) {

}
```

Use the `Integer#compare(int i1, int i2)` method to compare your two ids, return the value you receive from Integer compare.

Then simply use `Collections#sort(List<T>)` to sort your list.

Depending on the order you put i1 and i2 in you will receive an ascending or descending list, so play around until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your current code is not enough to make your requirements work.
you have to add few new functions for the LinkedList

For example, a function for insert object in the different index. 
A function for delete objects in the LinkedList.

I recommend you to create a Class called Comparator which can compare two objects and return the larger object.
Use the comparator with different sorting algorithms. If you don't know any sorting algorithms, bubble sort is the easiest way for sorting.

BTW, the best way is to use Binary Tree if you know what is it.